# How can microservices be truly independent when using an ESB (i.e. MassTransit)?

Tags: c#, esb, servicebus, masstransit, microservices

I'm doing some initial investigation into decomposing a current monolithic system by using MassTransit.  My main reason for going with a queue-based ESB is that the set of features I'm tackling first are using a shared database as, essentially, a queue.

I've also been reading "Building Microservices" and while I haven't yet finished it, one of the core tenets appears to be that microservices should essentially be standalone.

How can I reconcile using MassTransit which by necessity shares a message library (or at least contracts) and the fact that these services shouldn't have to "know" anything about each other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question is really about coupling. How coupled are your various services? 'Standalone' implies a level of loose coupling, but in order to interoperate, *some* level of coupling is required. The challenge is to couple as loosely as possible whilst maintaining the interoperability that will allow your components to work together to achieve your desired outcome.

A coupling via message contracts is a loose coupling. This only requires that each of your services knows and understands the 'shape' of the data (messages) that passes between them. The services have no need to share any code, hosts or even platforms.

When using an ESB, this shared knowledge of messages is the only thing that your services need to 'know' about each other. Depending on the type of transport you use, you may also need to give each service knowledge of the location (URI) of the other services, but again, this is a very loose coupling (spatial) and can be loosened further by, e.g. DNS. If you choose to use a brokered transport, e.g. centralised queuing technology like RabbitMQ, then this spatial coupling can be removed, but this comes with other trade-offs.

Bear in mind that MassTransit is not the only option available in the .NET space. E.g. a popular choice is [NServiceBus](http://particular.net/nservicebus) (full disclosure: I work for Particular Software and NSB is one of our products).

Comment: This is a great answer, I'd like to add that as a maintainer of MassTransit, I see people trying to shove behaviour into their messages. Coupling services together more tightly. We encourage people to use only interfaces for message contracts to help with this. Coupling isn't a huge deal with you have just a couple services. But what happens when you embrace this methodology to add features, you end up with 30 services. Then coupling becomes a real challenge.

Comment: Thanks, @Travis.  This is the approach I've been taking and while I'm still working through some of learning curve of MassTransit 3, "coupling" only via interfaces is working out nicely.